# How does wordpress link page templates to individual pages

Tags: pages, templates

According to [the Codex docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_File_Hierarchy), wordpress uses the query string and the template hierarchy to determine which template to use for a certain page.

> First, WordPress matches every Query String to query types — i.e. it decides what type of page (a search page, a category page, the home page etc.) is being requested. Templates are then chosen — and web page content is generated — in the order suggested by the WordPress Template hierarchy...

However, using Dashboard settings, you can hand pick templates for pages:

[image: screenshot of dashboard page attributes]

So, in this case, how does the Wordpress engine determine this, and where is the information stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored in post meta under the key `_wp_page_template`.

Comment: And that is so obvious I feel stupid for not finding it myself. Thanks!